# Is there a penalty under the law for attempted adultery?

Tags: halacha, reward-punishment, beit-din-court, arayot

If a married man or woman propositions sexual misconduct to a person, or a man or woman propositions a person they know is married, is there a prescribed penalty according to the law, i.e. would a a court of law apply any punishment, in practice?

Comment: Note that a married man's sleeping with an unmarried woman is a different prohibition from a married woman's sleeping with an unmarried man.

Comment: I doubt there's anything an earthly court would do; I can't say about the Heavenly Court. What do you mean when you say "according to the law"?

Comment: @Shokhet I mean according to the Torah and the Talmud.

Comment: @DoubleAA "Sleeping with" yes. But is the laying down necessary to incur penalty? Some of the English words used are "lay with" or "uncover your/her nakedness." If a woman for example, reported to her husband that a man exposed himself to her in an attempt to seduce her, does the husband have any recourse?

Comment: @Andrew Still a little unclear.....what I meant to ask you was, is your question about whether a Jewish court of law would take action to punish this, or whether God would punish this? ....you could have the second without having the first.

Comment: I happened to find an answer to your question when I was learning something else, but I can't post it here until I know what you meant to ask -- do you want to know if a court of law will punish this, or what God thinks about it?

Comment: I'm asking about a court of law. I'm certain it's wicked in the eyes of God.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. Tip for you: important information fits better in the actual question, rather than in the comment section, because the information will be a lot more visible that way.

Comment: Also, if you'd like to get someone's attention in comments, you can write their username, preceded by the `@` symbol. I didn't see your response to my comment, and happened upon this question by luck, looking for something else. I hope you find a good answer! :)

Comment: It can be more generalized, and as far as I know, "attempted" crimes generally don't get punished

Comment: Like מכת מרדות?

Comment: Where in the Talmud or Halacha does it say exactly that sin starts (or can start) in the heart? I know the Tanach says that. If it is verified by our sages or Halacha, then yes, Heaven at least has a penalty for an attempted sin (of adultery, for example), no?

Answer (score -1):

In parashat matot the beginning it says if a woman thought that her vow was still in effect, but it had been already nullified by the husband and there is no prohibition, and she "violates", she still needs atonement. This shows that even the attempt to sin needs atonement.

Rabbi Akiva commented on this: if we see even an attempt needs atonement, surely if one actually sinned that they need atonement. See Rashi there.

Comment: Does the need for atonement entail punishability/penalty "under the law"?

Comment: Does the need for atonement entail punishability "under the law"?

Comment: @josef mizrachi - how does that answer the question?